# Override equals method to return false while inserting to HashMap

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapTest {
    public String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return 100;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object te){
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapTest obj = new MapTest();
        MapTest obj1 = new MapTest();
        obj.setId("test");
        obj1.setId("test2");
        Map<MapTest,Integer> test = new HashMap<MapTest,Integer>(); 
        test.put(obj, 1000);
        test.put(obj1, 2000);
        test.put(new MapTest(), 4000);
        System.out.println(test.get(obj)); //1000
        System.out.println(test.get(obj1));//2000
        System.out.println(test.get(new MapTest()));//Null
        System.out.println(test.size());//3
    }

}
```

Here the object returns same hashcodes so inorder to avoid overwriting while adding data to HashMap I have a equals method that returns false. Now when I use get I get the proper data example obj1 and obj are giving exact values but my question is when both their hashcodes are same how java distinguishes different objects and return their exact values from hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in how HashMap implements the get method. When it checks the equality of the given key against the keys stored in the map (when they have equal hashcode value), it first does a reference equality check. The code below is taken from Java 8's implementation of get and as you see, there is the `==` check for the keys.

```
if (e.hash == hash &&
   ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
      return e;
```

If you use another object, with the same id value, it will not work, as there is no structural equality defined in your objects. Try this:

```
TestMap obj2 = new TestMap();
obj2.setId("test");
System.out.println(test.get(obj2)); // Returns Null
```

Answer (score 1):

The hashcode equals is the first requirement for hashmap to decide whether two keys the same, but not the only one/

(key1 == key2 || key1.equals(key2)) is also needed.

If you change your equals method to always return true, you can see there will be only one element in the map at last.